# How to start the map camera on user location and automatically follow him

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-jetpack-compose

I'm a beginner making a compose project and I use GoogleMap() function to display a map I need this map to start on the user's current location and need the map camera to follow the user when he moves without having to press a button.

I tried using LocationRequest to get user location but I don't actually now how to use it

Comment: The [Maps Compose Library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/compose) has a `LocationTrackingActivity.kt` that demonstrates something similar. Maybe you could play around with it and see if you can understand how it works.